# How to add a custom library in project Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a custom library and use it in Flutter project.

I created a custom library in project:

[image: Demo]

But I can't get pub it. (Error)

`Because write_library_external depends on lib_math from path which doesn't exist (could not find package lib_math at "..\lib_math"), version solving failed.
pub get failed (66; Because write_library_external depends on lib_math from path which doesn't exist (could not find package lib_math at "..\lib_math"), version solving failed.)`

This is my `pubspec.yaml`

```js
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  lib_math:
    path: /lib_math

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: I think you added the wrong library `path`!

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen how to fix it? I tried changing many paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you added the wrong library `path`.

With your project, you should try changing the file at `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  lib_math:
    path: ../write_library_external/library/lib_math
```